# Detailed mapping of how many pessukim there are in each perek of Torah (Chummish with 5845 pessukim)

Tags: pentateuch-chumash

BS"D

I looking for a detailed mapping of how many pessukim there are in each perek of Torah (Chummish with 5845 pessukim)

as opposed to 5888 pessukim  mapped here
https://catholic-resources.org/Bible/OT-Statistics-NAB.htm

Thank You

Comment: Is this on topic? This is like asking how many words are in each page of the king james bible

Comment: BS"D There are different mappings of the Torah. A gemorah (Kiddushin 30a) says there are 5888 pessukim. Others say 5845. I downloaded from Mechon-Mamre a copy of Torah that has 5845. I was ultimately looking for a structure map/index that included the Parshas . After searching the web unsuccessfully, I have tried to build such a mapping myself - It seemed to me that my question/request was on topic - no offence was intended

Comment: BS"D Further to my comments above - there also different opinions about how many pessukim there are in both Parsha Yisro and Parsha Va'eschanan. So it's been a challenge to get a complete and correct mapping of the Torah that I downloaded